# Google Auto Ads Adding Useless P

Tags: html, css, adsense, google-ads-api

If you go to my website https://iclintz.com/ and go to inspect and click on the mobile phone simulator and scroll down a little bit first, a google ad appears at the top, when you scroll back up to the very top, there is some padding that has been added and clicking on minimise on the google ad keeps the padding there. This issue is happening on all phones. I could not figure out why this is happening and there are no errors regarding this in the console log.

Screenshot here:
[image]

Any ideas for the cause of the issue or potential fixes? I've seen other sites that use google auto ads, but they do not suffer from the same problem.

Comment: The padding value is being set inline on the body element, possibly by javascript. I didn't see any empty <p> tags but removing the inline padding=top value 'fixed' it for me. I'd start by investigating where that padding is coming from.

Comment: I believe it is caused by google ads. When I remove the google .js file from the page, everything is working fine but obviously the ads aren't loading either.

Comment: This padding is added to prevent top anchor ad from hiding part of the webpage (e.g. if there is a logo or menu at the top). Otherwise ads will obstruct content and user will have to collapse the ad interact with menu. That padding should be automatically added on all sites that have top anchor so I'm surprised you didn't see it on other sites. I agree that it would be better if padding collapsed when ad is collapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was fixed after I went to AdSense settings and clicked on "apply to site" again. Seems like there was a bug the first time around.